# axios retry on error code response with delay

Tags: axios

I'm receiving data from api using axios, and i want to add error handling to it, i have different messages on different error codes received(401,400,503 etc), but i also want to set timeout of 1 min on 401 errors 2min on error code 500 etc.is that possible using axios without importing axios retry ? I tried coming up with a solution by using interceptors but then spread.js which is imported with axios spams the error in console log and causes browser freeze.I used the following code for timeout in interceptors

```
 axios.interceptors.response.use(function (response) {
                    // Do something with response data
                    console.log(response);
                    return response;
                }, function (error) {
                    // Do something with response error
                    if(error.response.status===401){
                        setTimeout(function (){
                            console.log(error.response.status===401);
                            return Promise.reject(error);
                        },10000);
                    }
                    if(error.response.status===503){
                        setTimeout(function (){
                            console.log(error.response.status===503);
                            return Promise.reject(error);
                        },30000);
                    }
                    if(error.response.status===500){
                        setTimeout(function (){
                            console.log(error.response.status===401);
                            return Promise.reject(error);
                        },50000);
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Did you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to return your `setTimeout()` in order for it to work. You could use `else-if`s in your code to make it more efficient

```
axios.interceptors.response.use(function(response) {
  console.log(response);
  return response;
}, function(error) {
  if (error.response.status === 401) {
    return setTimeout(function() {
      console.log(error.response.status === 401);
      return Promise.reject(error);
    }, 10000);
  }
  else if (error.response.status === 503) {
    return setTimeout(function() {
      console.log(error.response.status === 503);
      return Promise.reject(error);
    }, 30000);
  }
  else if (error.response.status === 500) {
    return setTimeout(function() {
      console.log(error.response.status === 401);
      return Promise.reject(error);
    }, 50000);
  }
  else {
    return Promise.reject(error)
  }
});
```